# How install flask on server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, python

I developed an application with python flask framework.I have account in shared host. they support python and i have ssh access to server.
But when i tried

`pip install flask`

and

```
easy_install flask
```

it say no write permission in bin folder.
So the possible solution is install flask in local directory.
How can i install flask locally without sudo permission ?

Comment: Have you read the [Flask Installation Documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/#installation)?  You will still have to ask your hosting provider to install virtualenv for you if it isn't already available.

Comment: Questions concerning the use of **shared web hosting by end users or resellers**, rather than the administration of web hosting, are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

pip has an option to install to your home directory.

```
pip install --user flask
```